# Show $A^*A$ is self adjoint for $A$ closed and description of the form domain.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have been stuck with the next problem

> Suppose $A$ is a closed operator defined on $\mathfrak{D}(A)\subset \mathfrak{H}$, where $\mathfrak{H}$ is a Hilbert space. Show that $B=A*A$ is self adjoint with domain $\mathfrak{D}(B)=\{\psi\in\mathfrak{D}(A)|A\psi\in\mathfrak{D}(A*)\}$. Show that $\mathfrak{O}(B)=\mathfrak{D}(A)$.

Here, $\mathfrak{O}(B)$ is the form domain of the quadratic form associated with $B$, which is defined as the completion of $D(B)$ with the metric induced by the scalar product

$$
(x,y)_B=(x,(B+1)y)
$$

And seen as a subspace of $\mathfrak{H}$.
I have already shown that $B$ is self adjoint and I found another proof here on the site, but what causes me troubles is the last part of the statement. Using that $A$ is closed, one can easily show that $\mathfrak{O}(B)\subset\mathfrak{D}(A)$. But I'm stuck showing the another contention.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator $A$ is closed. So $Y=\mathcal{D}(A)$ is a Hilbert space under the graph inner-product
$$
              (x,y)_A = (x,y)+(Ax,Ay).
$$
This is the same as your form norm on $\mathcal{D}(A^{\star}A)$.
Your question is equivalent to asking if $\mathcal{D}(A^\star A)$ is dense in $Y$.

To prove that $\mathcal{D}(A^{\star}A)$ is dense in the form space, suppose $y \in Y$ is orthogonal to $\mathcal{D}(A^\star A)$ in $Y$. Equivalently,
$$
                    (x,y)+(Ax,Ay) = 0,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A^{\star}A),\\
                 (x+A^{\star}Ax,y)=0,\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(A^{\star}A).
$$
Because $A^\star A$ is selfadjoint and non-negative, then $A^\star A+I$ is surjective, which forces $y=0$. Therefore $\mathcal{D}(A^{\star}A)$ is dense in $Y$, which means that the form space is the same as the graph of $A$.